# Understanding the Next_Permutation Function in C++ for a Vector of Objects

Tags: c++, parameters, operator-overloading, permutation

I would like help figuring out how to use the `next_permutation` function on a vector of objects. I've read about people using the `comp` parameter, but I don't understand it. I thought the overloaded operators would fix things, but I'm still getting thrown errors. Please help me with my syntax and/or explain (with examples) the `comp` parameter of the `next_permutation` function! Thanks!

In my main file:

```
vector<Point> source;

//fill vector with Points, say 4 of them (1,2)(2,3)(3,4)(4,5)

next_permutation(source.begin(), source.end()); // at run I get error "Invalid operands to binary expression ('Const Point' and 'Const Point)"
```

My simple Point class:

```
class Point {
private:
    double xval, yval;
public:
    Point(int x = 0, int y = 0) {
        xval = x;
        yval = y;
    }

    int x() { return xval; }
    int y() { return yval; }

    friend bool operator<(Point& lhs, Point& rhs){
        return lhs.x() < rhs.x() || (lhs.x()==rhs.x() && lhs.y()<rhs.y()) ;
    }

    friend bool operator==(Point& lhs, Point& rhs) {
        return lhs.x()==rhs.x() && lhs.y()==rhs.y();
    }

};
```

EDIT: This also throws the same error:

```
int x() const { return xval; }
int y() const { return yval; }

friend bool operator<(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs){
    return lhs.x() < rhs.x() || (lhs.x()==rhs.x() && lhs.y()<rhs.y()) ;
}

friend bool operator==(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
    return lhs.x()==rhs.x() && lhs.y()==rhs.y();
}
```

This also throws the same error:

```
int x() const { return xval; }
int y() const { return yval; }

bool operator<(const Point& lhs){
    return lhs.x() < x() || (lhs.x()==x() && lhs.y()<y()) ;
}

bool operator==(const Point& lhs) {
    return lhs.x()==x() && lhs.y()==y();
}
```

Comment: Comparison operators shouldn't be allowed to modify objects, and shouldn't unnecessarily be friends.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @chris, but I don't know how to execute that. If I take away the 'friend' and change the .x() to .xval and .y() to .yval, I get errors. If I then also only have one parameter, I still get errors. Could you write out better syntax for me to follow?

Comment: Make the getters const, use them, make the `Point &` parameters of the comparison operators const and remove `friend`.

Comment: I've done this:

`int x() const { return xval; }`

`int y() const { return yval; }`
    
`bool operator<(const Point& rhs){return x() < rhs.x() ||(x()==rhs.x() && y()<rhs.y()) ;}`
    
`bool operator==(const Point& rhs) {return x()==rhs.x() && y()==rhs.y();}`

But it throws the same error at runtime. Anything else I'm missing here?

Comment: Doing approximately the same, http://liveworkspace.org/code/3pYMQv%242

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me on this @chris! I copy pasted the code from that link and got the same error message described above. Any ideas?
If I comment out the `next_permutation` line, it compiles fine, but with it, I get that error. Using xcode 4.5.1

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: The problem is that you made the comparison operators a *nonconst* member function, so the first argument is not const, thus the error.

Answer (score 1):

Use const references and const getter functions.

```
int x() const { return xval; }
int y() const { return yval; }

friend bool operator<(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs){
    return lhs.x() < rhs.x() || (lhs.x()==rhs.x() && lhs.y()<rhs.y()) ;
}

friend bool operator==(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) {
    return lhs.x()==rhs.x() && lhs.y()==rhs.y();
}
```

http://liveworkspace.org/code/4Drerr$0

Comment: Thanks @ForEveR! This allows the next_permutation to work as expected, except I had to change the .x() and .y() to .xval and .yval accordingly.

Comment: @ruya: We should find out why, because you should not have to and you do not want to.

Answer (score 0):

Getter functions should be const member function, also any reason you convert from double to int?

Try:

```
double x() const { return xval; }
double y() const { return yval; }
```

Comment: I have no good reason to convert from double to int! Haha, thanks for catching that.